# Отправить текст в Text View

Tags: java, android

Есть Fragment у него есть TextView, я его объявил в onCreateView но за его пределами оно его не "видит"

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);

    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    return view;
}


private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    String result = response.body().string();

    text.setText(result);

}
```

Тоесть я пытаюсь отправить ответ сервера в TextView `text.setText(result)` , но увы. В чем  моя ошибка?

Comment: У Вас подчеркивается text красным?

Comment: нет, я написал text.setText("текст") в onCreateView, текст вью поменяло текст. я сделал то же самое в run() текст не поменялся

Comment: Это не проблема видимости TextView, так бы text подсвечивался красным. На самом деле судя по вопросам Вам еще очень рано лезть в сеть. Лучше изучите Java Core, потом Android Fundamentals, а потом осваивайте Network, это так, совет.

Comment: Ну дела то не столько в сети. Когда я создавал обычный активити, там мне все было понятно, "сверху" я объявил текст вью, указал id куда обращаться к текст вью и все работало. Вопросы начались во Fragment

Comment: тут скорей все не отрабатывает  text.setText(result); т.к. до этого происходит ошибка или он вставляет пустой текст или run() вообще не вызывается.

Comment: А метод `run()`-то вообще вызывается?

Comment: `execute()` делает синхронный запрос в сеть. Значит тут два варианта (если метод `run()` вообще вызывается): 1. Вы делаете его в UI потоке и получаете NetworkOnMainThreadException. 2. Вы делаете его в бекграунд потоке и получаете CalledFromWrongThreadException когда пытаетесь установить текст. Добавьте стектрейс в вопрос.